Complete disable bluetooth Ubuntu 22.04
I'am running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS server version on a Raspberry Pi 4. I don't need Bluetooth and want to disable the service.

I stopped and disabled the system services,

I blacklisted the modules (sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf) and rebuilt with sudo update-initramfs -u,

on each startup a service with ExecStart=/bin/bash -c 'rfkill block 0 && rfkill block 1' is called, so rfkill list shows blocked bluetooth as expected.


But when I run systemctl list-units --type=service, I see that  Bluetooth.service is active and bthelper@hci0.service has status "failed".
How can I disable bluetooth completely?

How did you disable the system service? What command did you use? That alone should have been enough. Also, please [edit] the question and add the output of sudo service bluetooth (or Bluetooth or whatever the service is called).

At least, masking the bluetooth services helps. I also thought, that stoping and disabling the bluetooth service should be enough, but it wasn't. Now sudo systemctl mask bluetooth.service and systemctl mask bthelper@hci0.servicehelps.
